# I have an array of dynamic data, how to display that with ordered list as mega menu

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display a mega menu dynamically coming from database.

```
Array
(
    [PROPERTIES] => Array
        (
            [0] => ([sub_category_name] => For Sale: Houses & Apartments )
            [1] => ([sub_category_name] => For Rent: Houses & Apartments  )
        )

    [CARS] => Array
        (
            [0] => ([sub_category_name] => Commercial Vehicles)
        )

    [FURNITURE] => Array
        (
            [0] => ([sub_category_name] => Sofa & Dining )
            [1] =>( [sub_category_name] => Home Decor & Garden)
            [2] =>([sub_category_name] => Kids Furniture)
        )
    [JOBS] => Array
        (
            [0] => ([sub_category_name] => Sales & Marketing    )

            [1] =>([sub_category_name] => Data entry & Back office    )
        )
    [BOOKS, SPORTS & HOBBIES] => Array
        (
            [0] =>([sub_category_name] => Gym & Fitness
                )
        )
    [MOBILES] => Array
        (
            [0] =>([sub_category_name] => Mobile Phones)

            [1] => ([sub_category_name] => Accessories)
        )
)
```

I want to display result as below image:
[image]
Same like the image i want show the key value as Main Category. sub category as sub menu for that main category

Comment: How do you get the results now?

Comment: We are not here to code for you, if you have something and it is not working then we can help you with it.

Comment: "_I want to ..._" is not a question. What have you done already to achieve that? Please post your code and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of foreach loops should do the trick:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
 'properties' => array(
     0 => array(
         'sub' => 'hello'
        ),
     1 => array(
         'sub' => 'world'
        )
    ),
  'cars' => array(
     0 => array(
         'sub' => 'hello1'
        ),
     1 => array(
         'sub' => 'world2'
        )
    )
);

print_r($arr);

echo '<ul>';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    echo '<li>' . $key . '</li>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($value as $item) {
        echo '<li>' . $item['sub'] . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';

}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: i used above code. still am not getting the proper answer. in my menu am getting the Properties category side by side. am unable to get the result same as the image

Comment: the styling is completely up to you - this isn't a code writing service, just a nudge in the right direction.